# Cannot use child class' properties within parent class constructor via Babel's transform-class-properties

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, babeljs, ecmascript-next

When extending a parent class and declaring the child class' properties via Babel's 'transform-class-properties' plugin, any class properties of the child class are not accessible via the parent class' constructor method.

```
class One {

    internal = 1;

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor internal', this.internal);
    }

}

class Two extends One {

    internal = 2;

}

new Two();
```

In the example above, 'constructor internal 1' will be output to the console. When looking at the compiled code this is obvious as to why, with the parent class being executed first and the resulting object then being integrated with the child class.

Apologies if this is by design, but it has confused me as the following code works in the way I am expecting within non-constructor methods (so the boot() method references the child class' 'internal' property value):

```
class One {

    internal = 1;

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor internal', this.internal);
    }

    boot() {
        console.log('boot internal', this.internal);
    }

}

class Two extends One {

    internal = 2;

    constructor() {
            super();

            this.boot();
    }

}

new Two();
```

So, even when calling a method declared on the parent class, it will inherit the child class' properties. It is just constructor methods which seemingly do not behave as expected (at least by me - again, apologies if this is wrongly interpreted, but there are no caveats listed on the relative Babel page.)

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is by design. Don't access overwritable properties (or methods) in the constructor. Don't execute side effects in the constructor, only initialise properties.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You seem to have found a solution already (though you'd better not call `boot` from the constructor, rather do `new Two().boot()`)

Comment: After playing with this some more, I have found 2 ways of bypassing this issue, but I am still very interested in knowing if it's possible to access child properties without doing the following:

#1 Static properties

 class One {
  static a = 1;
  constructor() {
   console.log(this.constructor.a);
  }
 }
 class Two extends One {
 static a= 2;
 }
 new Two();

#2 Getter methods

 class One {
  get a() {
   return 1
  };
  constructor() {
   console.log(this.a);
  }
 }
 class Two extends One {
  get a() {
   return 2;  
  }
 }
 new Two();

Comment: No, the parent constructor is always executed first, before you can do anything to the instance. You can try passing the value as an argument, though.

Comment: Thank you Bergi, and sorry for the formatting (I was still writing that when you'd already responding twice!). The issue was simply trying to write elegant code for a certain situation. I shall rely on one of the less-elegant examples I supplied or, do what would probably be wiser, use a factory instead. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Funny, I found this example on the preact doc page https://preactjs.com/guide/extending-component that seems to be using the very feature you are talking about. It does not work, though, or maybe it needs some special babel configuration. See the "MixedComponent" class at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loganfsmyth answered my question very clearly here: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7567 (Thanks!)

> This is indeed expected behavior. Babel's implementation is a little incorrect because in a perfect world this would also throw an error, because you shouldn't have the same property defined in a parent and a child, but we don't do that right at the moment.
>
> Class properties are initialized when:
>
> - For base classes, before the constructor executes
> - For child classes, at the end of super()
>
> and when a given constructor initializes it's bindings, it uses that classes bindings, it doesn't know of anything in child classes. That means your One class knows the value should be 1, so that's what it sets.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is natural. If you wish to override the parent class's property init value, you should do it in the derived class's constructor.

```
class Two extends One {

    constructor() {
        // Call parent constructor.
        super();
        // Override here.
        this.internal = 2;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding (:

Comment: He already does that effectively. He's just wondering why the parent constructor doesn't see the overwritten value.

Comment: Thank you Jigar, I think I might use that pattern. It's very clean! Cheers.